# read_sql chunksize error

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a data-set (14gb) and I am trying to pull the data in from MySQL using `chunksize`. However, I continue to get the following error:

```
TypeError: read_sql_query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunksize'
```

Here is my code:

```
for chunk in pandas.read_sql_query(sql = SQL_QUERY, con = MYSQL_PHOENIX, chunksize = 10000):
    DO STUFF TO chunk
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is producing this error.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: Python Version 2.7.9

Comment: I mean __pandas__ version - you can check it in `pandas.__version__` variable

Comment: Oh yes sorry, Pandas 0.14.1

Comment: you'll have to upgrade your pandas in order to be able to use this parameter

Comment: Yep! Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chunksize` parameter for `pandas.read_sql_query` was introduced between `pandas` versions `0.14` and `0.15`, so you likely have an older version. Update if you can.